# How to make my sound reactive LEDs with Tip31C work?

Tags: arduino, led, amplifier, sound

I am building a rhythmic LED headphone prototype, but unfortunately I am missing something or am doing something wrong because my project is not working properly.
The project is as follows:
I bought

- A pair of one dollar headphones.
- Two tip31c transistors.
- One pam8403 module, to improve the signal of the two channels.
- Two 5 V LED plates for both right and left channels
- A USB cable.

I am using this diagram:
[image]

But something went wrong, because the pam8403 only works disconnecting the tip. I've tested the output right and left channel of pam8403 and works fine with speakers of test, but when I connect the tip31c in one or both channels it makes a (bip a sound hit in bot out channels) that it repeats infinitely, and the LEDds are blinking in a static sequence repeatedly infinitely, and not with all power, not following the music or music signal provided by the audio input plug...

I don't know if it's a problem of pam8403 or tip31c, important I need pam8403 because not all devices have the full power....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PAM8403 is a Class D bridging amplifier so you are shorting out one of the drivers by grounding it, among other things.

Try using just the + on each side and use an RC low-pass filter like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFoV8f.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You may have to try other values of R and C to get what you want.

Comment: Ok, then i have to use the positive signal of both channels instead the gnd, in the out of PAM8403, and use the filter that you post, right?

Comment: That's my suggestion. You still need the ground connected to the PAM, of course.

Comment: thank you, a high voltage line 12v can affect if i use the positive channels?

Comment: The 5V ground and the 12V ground must be connected together. The PAM8403 can only handle 5.5V maximum supply voltage or it will be destroyed.

Comment: Thanks, i will use the same then (5v) , i will test it, i hope select a answer today...

Comment: Uhmm, work but inverted, when the sound releases, the light is going down, but when the sound are falling the light is going up... i already made the filter that you say...

Comment: but i'm now are more closer, because now work inverted, and is much better than not work...

Comment: I've solve the problem using your method and inverting the emitter with the collector, and to solve the temperature problem, i've use the 100 ohms resistor without the capacitor, because capacitor stores energy making the blinking led delay more, and making the led keeps continously on...

Answer (score 0):

The outputs of the PAM8403 are at half the DC supply voltage which will keep the transistors and LEDs turned on most of the time. You need series input capacitors feeding the 100 ohm resistors to block the DC and you need a 10k resistor to ground at each transistor base.